# Using integer and shifting to imitate floating point operations

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

my question is scoping efficiency in a C++-Framework I'm currently developing. The context: I have two arrays equal in size. One of them contains point coordinates from a detected point cloud, the other one the corresponding color-values. The problem arose that the color values indices do not exactly match the point coordinates so the color array needs to be scaled.

To keep the efficiency of the system, I was advised to use the following "hack" to avoid floating point operations in order to let the shifted_row_index run slower than x in order to scale the color array index. Unfortunately the advisor is not available at the moment, and I don't understand why this solutions works in this case.

It would be nice of you, if someone could explain it to me. Thanks in advance!

```
int shifted_row_index = (RGB_OFFSET_X << 8);
for (int x = 0, xmax = g_depthMD.XRes(); x < xmax; x += raster_width)
{
     shifted_row_index += RGB_SCALE_FACTOR_X;
     int rowindex = shifted_row_index >> 8;
     rowindex = std::max(std::min(rowindex, (int)(xmax - 1)), 0);
     color_pointer[0] = pImageRow[rowindex].nRed;
     //....
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the purpose of this code is, so it's hard to explain how it achieves its goals...

Comment: @Oli: I *think* that `RGB_SCALE_FACTOR_X` is less than 256 (or anyway not a multiple), and the significant purpose of this code is just that it's in effect adding some value less than 1 (or anyway not an integer) to a running total each iteration. The running total therefore is `shifted_row_index / 256`, which has been pinhole optimized.

Answer (score 0):

The only "bit hack" operations I see are the left and right shift operations. I see no reason for you to use them as any reasonable compiler will optimize the code:

```
int shifted_row_index = (RGB_OFFSET_X * 64);
```

And

```
int rowindex = shifted_row_index / 64;
```

To be just as efficient.

Comment: To make signed division as efficient as right-shift you either need a division instruction that's just as fast as the shift instruction (unlikely), or else you need to somehow establish that the input value is non-negative for free. I don't think it's quite clear here that "any reasonable compiler" can do that, but it can at least get pretty close to the same performance.

Comment: OTOH you might question whether an index should be signed, for precisely that reason.

Comment: I think most of the present compilers will simply replace the multiplication with bit shift and I think I have benchmarked a few times to verify both versions are equally optimized.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: the multiplication yes, it's the division that's tricky because `-1 / 2` is 0, not -1 (required since C++11, but even before then most implementations rounded toward 0). If `RGB_OFFSET_X` is a compile-time constant then the multiplication might not appear in the emitted code at all.

Comment: @SteveJessop Could you give an example when doing `shifted_row_index / 64;` is noticeably slower than `shifted_row_index >> 8;`?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: I can give you an example where it's more instructions, if you're prepared to accept that as a proxy for actually being slower. Whether more instructions are slower or not depends on a whole bunch of stuff including the state of the pipeline, but the additional check for negative input is unlikely to make it any faster.